# Arduino Upgrading from 1.0.6 to 1.6, code doesn't work anymore

Tags: arduino-ide, compile

I'm using Arduino UNO, and today I upgraded my IDE from 1.0.6 to 1.6, just to upgrade, nothing special.

I got my libraries again but I got an error with a code that was working OK.

The error was:

```
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:223:0,
                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\ModbusMaster-master\ModbusMaster.h:53,
                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\ModbusMaster-master\ModbusMaster.cpp:32:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/HardwareSerial.h: In member function 'HardwareSerial& HardwareSerial::operator=(const HardwareSerial&)':
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/HardwareSerial.h:83:7: error: non-static const member 'volatile uint8_t* const HardwareSerial::_ubrrh', can't use default assignment operator
 class HardwareSerial : public Stream
       ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/HardwareSerial.h:83:7: error: non-static const member 'volatile uint8_t* const HardwareSerial::_ubrrl', can't use default assignment operator
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/HardwareSerial.h:83:7: error: non-static const member 'volatile uint8_t* const HardwareSerial::_ucsra', can't use default assignment operator
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/HardwareSerial.h:83:7: error: non-static const member 'volatile uint8_t* const HardwareSerial::_ucsrb', can't use default assignment operator
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/HardwareSerial.h:83:7: error: non-static const member 'volatile uint8_t* const HardwareSerial::_ucsrc', can't use default assignment operator
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/HardwareSerial.h:83:7: error: non-static const member 'volatile uint8_t* const HardwareSerial::_udr', can't use default assignment operator
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\ModbusMaster-master\ModbusMaster.cpp: In member function 'void ModbusMaster::begin(uint16_t)':
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\ModbusMaster-master\ModbusMaster.cpp:139:16: note: synthesized method 'HardwareSerial& HardwareSerial::operator=(const HardwareSerial&)' first required here 
       MBSerial = Serial;
                ^
```

I couldn't find the real error, can someone help me?

Comment: Can you share the whole sketch?

Comment: Libraries for 1.0 aren't automatically compatible with 1.5 or 1.6. You can just comment out all the assignments like `MBSerial = ...` and replace all calls to `MBSerial.whatever` to `Serial.whatever` in `ModbusMaster.cpp`.

Comment: Thanks Gerben, I tried changing the ModbusMaster.cpp but it still does not work. But the IDE haven't change the things that I was expecting, so the easy way for me is to go back to the 1.0.6 version. But thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the error messages you were using a ModbusMaster library from GitHub such as [this one](https://github.com/4-20ma/ModbusMaster) and the HardwareSerial library from the Arduino IDE.

I think the key is in the statement:

> I got my libraries again

I would suggest that you have downloaded a different library to what you originally used. Even if you did get the same repository, these libraries are also constantly changing and your code sometimes has to evolve with the library.

You have several errors (with the SoftwareSerial library): `non-static const member, can't use default assignment operator`. Essentially the program is trying to assign a value to a const or perhaps assigning a constant pointer to non-const data. Find more information on the error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030972/type-non-static-const-member-cant-use-default-assignment-operator-what-does) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634662/non-static-const-member-cant-use-default-assignment-operator). All of these errors stem from line 83 of HardwareSerial.h.

The last line(s) give the clue. You are assigning your instance of your Serial object to you MBSerial object.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have added libraries to the Arduino files in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino" folder in the first place.
That is only for the Arduino program files and standard libraries that are included with the Arduino IDE.

Could you uninstall the Arduino and serial drivers. Remove also the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino" folder, to be sure that absolutely nothing is left behind, because that will interfere with a new version that will be installed. Remove also the hidden "arduino15" folder(s).
Do you know the location of your sketches, it is in the preferences and is often "Documents\Arduino". Go to that folder and go into the "libraries" folder. Remove unused libraries or libraries that have been included in the Arduino files.
Do you have Java installed ? Some Java versions are not compatible with the Java files of the Arduino. If you don't need Java, then uninstall it.

Install the newest Arduino 1.8.3 from [Arduino.cc Software](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software).
Use the Library Manager in the Arduino IDE, and search for modbus. Install the "ModbusMaster by Doc Walker" with the Library Manager. The modbus library that will be installed is this one: [Github 4-20mA ModbusMaster](https://github.com/4-20ma/ModbusMaster).

There has been a few changes, for example with PROGMEM. All PROGMEM data must now be 'const'. You might have to make a few adjustments.